# Missing optional dependency in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I have encountered this error yesterday which I've already resolved by installing the missing optional dependency. But today as I started another Python file in PyCharm I'm getting the same error again.

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

Does anyone knows why this might be happening?

I tried again now to install it and pip confirmed that it's already installed.

```
C:\Users\Ben>pip install xlrd
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\ben\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2.0.1)
```

Comment: I wonder whether the Python version on PyCharm is different from pip on the command line. Check the versions of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that `xlrd` is installed in your user wide `site-packages` but pycham uses different virtual environments for every project. This probably means that `xlrd` isn't installed in your project's virtual environment. You can try doing the following in your terminal:

1. Open a terminal and CD into your project's directory. There should be a directory named venv
2. Type the following command

```
.\venv\bin\activate
```

Now you should see the name of your virtual environment in braces in your shell. Something like this - `(venv)C:\path\to\project>`

3. Now that you are using the virtual environment, you can install xlrd by typing

```
pip install xlrd
```

You can read more about virtual environments [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3239675/virtualenv-and-venv-python-virtual-environments-explained.html)

Comment: Actually, I found the activate script under the .\venv\Scripts folder instead of the .\venv\bin folder. I'm guessing different versions of Python PyCharm creates the folder structure differently? But following your advised steps worked.

Comment: I think that `venv/bin/activate/` is the path in linux which I am using, and `\venv\Script\activate` is that path in windows

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll keep it in mind for when I need to do the same on Linux. For now, I'm doing a course and working on my home PC - Windows box.